# Where is the ASP.NET Core 2.2 temp-directory in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

For ASP.NET MVC5 (.net4.8) the ASP.NET temporary directories are:

```
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

But I can't figure out which are the temporary directories for ASP.NET Core (ASP.NET Core 2.2 if it makes any difference).

Clarification: Our ASP.NET Core 2.2 websites run with their AppPool .Net CLR version set to "No Managed Code" (we run these websites in in-process mode by employing the AspNetCoreModuleV2).

Clarification#2: As @PanagiotisKanavos correctly pointed out, under normal conditions, we shouldn't be accessing anything in such temp folders. However we've run into a freak accident with our dlls in one of our ASP.NET Core 2.2 websites which causes some sort of old/cached dlls to keep getting loaded inside VS causing exceptions (yes, we have deep-cleaned our VS solutions + C:\Temp + global nuget cache-folders but no joy). In our effort to troubleshoot it in PCs which exhibit this behavior we thought to manually reset the ASP.NET cache (if it exists at all) for our ASP.NET Core websites.

Comment: Why do you care? You shouldn't be accessing anything in that folder. In any case .NET Core works in a very different way - especially on Linux or MacOS. Are you looking for some temporary DLL or cache? Or trying to delete them to get over some problem?

Comment: It is in the same directory as other versions, if it does not appear to you you probably do not have it installed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the prompt response. You're absolutely right. Under normal conditions, we shouldn't be accessing anything in that folder. However we've run into a freak accident with our dlls in one of our ASP.NET Core 2.2 websites which causes some sort of old dlls to keep getting loaded inside VS causing exceptions (yes, we have deep-cleaned our VS solutions + C:\Temp + global nuget cache-folders but no joy). In our effort to troubleshoot it in PCs which exhibit this behavior we thought to manually reset the ASP.NET cache (if it exists at all) for our ASP.NET Core websites.

Comment: @XDS add that information in the question itself

Comment: Yeah, this is an XY problem. Ask about your *actual* issue, not what you *think* might solve it, which in this case won't anyways.